# com.google.android.maps.MapView ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, google-maps, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to do a google maps activity but I get a LogCat error and my app crashes. I used the coding provided by android when I registered my API key so I don't know why it doesn't work. I need help solving this.

LogCat

```
08-10 11:04:38.854: W/dalvikvm(702): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/maps/google/Main; (402)
08-10 11:04:38.854: W/dalvikvm(702): Link of class 'Lcom/maps/google/Main;' failed
08-10 11:04:38.854: D/AndroidRuntime(702): Shutting down VM
08-10 11:04:38.854: W/dalvikvm(702): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.maps.google/com.maps.google.Main}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.maps.google.Main
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.maps.google.Main
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
08-10 11:04:38.874: E/AndroidRuntime(702):  ... 11 more
```

XML File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/MView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="02ooeHTBsCB6ez4yyEGFEyiuNCz5hTHubgxBMfg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java file

```
package com.maps.google;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends MapActivity {

    MapView map;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.MView);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in your manifest file?

Comment: are u using an emulator that uses the google api's?

Comment: @ M Mohsin Naeem :Thanks, this worked great

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add `<uses-library` like this in your `manifest` file.

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.package.name">
  ...
  <application android:name="MyApplication" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    ...
  </application>
  ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please note that sometimes adding the "uses" line within Eclipse does not take hold, try an external editor after getting out of Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have included the following line in your application manifest:

```
<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

and make sure it's in the correct place. My problem (had similar error messages) was that I had put this in there but like the uses-permission stuff it was just under the root element manifest, when in fact the uses-library element is suppose to be placed under the application element. In case I wasn't clear enough see the part: Configuring the application manifest from Sameers link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the google map classes in your project?

You will need to add the maps jar file to your project.

The jar can be found in your
`{ANDROID-SDK_HOME}\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_*\libs` directory.

Here are two other questions that would possibly help you with your situation.

1. [i-want-to-get-library-for-com-google-android-maps-to-add-my-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409936/i-want-to-get-library-for-com-google-android-maps-to-add-my-project)
2. [google-maps-android-api-gives-a-noclassdeffounderror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792148/google-maps-android-api-gives-a-noclassdeffounderror)