# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.maps.MapView"

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to add Map functionality to my app. My IDE is `AndroidStudio`. I've gone to the SDK Manager and installed both `Google Play services` and `Google repository`.

Then, in my gradle file, I've added `google play services`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

After this, I've synced the project with the gradle files.

In my fragment, I've added `MapView` (and my API key). No error during compile, however, I get this during runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.maps.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.blueforcemedia.blueforcetracker-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Build Path=>Configure Build Path, then add the external jar. Also check the permissions..https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Comment: I am new to AndroidStudio. Where is Build Path? Thanks!

Comment: right click on project, then select build path and them configure build path

Comment: @ajitksharma When I right click on project, there's no option 'build path'

Comment: I suspect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904691/com-google-android-maps-mapview-classnotfoundexception?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The library was provided during the compile, but it's not present at runtime. Your application  is trying to invoke a method from library which is not present.

Comment: How can I make sure it's there on runtime?

Comment: Maybe this would help : 
http://geekswithblogs.net/cyberycon/archive/2011/05/17/using-external-libraries-with-android.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Once i have got this exception for not adding the **launcher icon** in the manifest.xml(tag) and also for not setting up the target project properties correctly.